# How to install SSH in app service container

Tags: azure, docker, containers, azure-web-app-service

I need to login to a linux container hosted in an app service via SSH (the image doesn't have it installed) in order to copy some files. Is there a way to do this via the portal? I'd like to avoid extending the image if possible. I tried fiddling with the startup command available in the UI with no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: Follow this tutorial from MS, you'll learn on it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/create-linux-virtual-machine-in-azure/

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? Or what you exactly expect?

Comment: Why not give any response? Do you still want to solve the problem? Or you just ignore the help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the Web App, SSH is supported, but you need to [configure the SSH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/configure-custom-container#enable-ssh) yourself when you use the custom image. Only the built-in images which Azure Web App provided can use the SSH directly without configuring yourself. When you use the built-in image, you can go into the Kudu and the SSH is already configured there.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to configure ssh or something equivalent for the windows-based containers?

Comment: Yes, follow this instruction here for windows configuration - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?tabs=debian&pivots=container-linux#enable-ssh

Answer (score 0):

I am running my Docker Container in local machine, to Use SSH utility I have perform following steps

**Step 1: Login to Docker Container using docker command**

```
$ docker exec -it <container_id or container_name> /bin/bash
```

**Step 2: Install SSH Server**

```
$ apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-server
```

**Step 3 Create SSH-keypair in your local machine **

You can Skip this step if you have SSH-keypair in your ~/.ssh directory

```
$ ssh-keygen
```

- Keep Default Path for storing Key Pair.
- and for this *Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):* Just press Enter

**Step 4: Copy the Content of Public key file to Docker ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file**

- From Local machine

`$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Now Copy that Public Key

- Inside Docker container

`$ mkdir -p ~/.ssh && chmod 700 ~/.ssh`

```
$ echo "<Public-Key content>" > ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

$ chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

**Step 5: Update SSH Configuration and restart SSH Service Inside Docker Container**

Open file /etc/ssh/sshd_config and remove comment from following line

> PubkeyAuthentication yes

This command is use to restart SSH Service to affect the changes.

```
$ service ssh restart
```

and Check the status of SSH Service to check it's running or not

```
$ service ssh status
```

**Step 6: Get Docker Container I.P.**

From Local machine run following Command

```
$ docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' <container_name or container_id>
```

**Step 7:Perform SSH**

```
$ ssh root@<Container_IP>
```

You can also use SCP.

```
$ scp <file_name> root@<container_ip>:
```

Comment: "apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-server" gives "13: Permission denied"